# Extracting object values from JSON in Athena/Presto

Tags: presto, amazon-athena, trino

I have a column with `JSON` objects. I need to extract all values from this objects. The problem is the keys are not fixed and contains some ids, so I can't extract values by exact key value. Here is an example:

```
{
    "1220202132188388": {
        "id": "1220202132188388",
        "date": "2019-04-03"
    },
    "482928839992": {
        "id": "482928839992",
        "date": "2019-04-06"
    }
}
```

So I'd like to get an array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1220202132188388",
    "date": "2019-04-03"
  },
  {
    "id": "482928839992",
    "date": "2019-04-06"
  }
]
```

Presto has limited JSONPath support and `$.*` doesn't work. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast json to map and use [map_values](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/map.html#map_values) function.

```sql
select
 map_values(cast(json_parse(c1) as map<varchar, json>)) 
from 
(
    values '{
    "1220202132188388": {
        "id": "1220202132188388",
        "date": "2019-04-03"
    },
    "482928839992": {
        "id": "482928839992",
        "date": "2019-04-06"
    }
}'
) t(c1)
```

```
[{"id":"1220202132188388","date":"2019-04-03"}, {"id":"482928839992","date":"2019-04-06"}]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It is exactly what I need!

Comment: You can also ask such questions in community Slack. https://prestosql.io/slack.html